# Enable disable button based on WPF datagrid selected rows following MVVM c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF app I have a datagrid

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelItm ,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          Name="myGrid"...
```

Now I want to enable a button if any rows of the datagrid are selected, if no rows are selected the button should be disabled, pretty simple stuff.

My button xaml is like

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding PreviewButtonClicked}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelItm, ElementName=myGrid}"
```

I've create a standard RelayCommand class

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

and my viewmodel class contains:

```
public class myVM()
{
    private string _SelItm;
    public string SelItm
    {
        get { return _SelItm; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ref _SelItm, value);
        }
    }
  public RelayCommand PreviewButtonClicked { get; set; }

  public myVM()
  {
    PreviewButtonClicked = new RelayCommand(ShowPDF, CanShowPDF);
  }
  
  public void ShowPDF(object param)
  {
    //do stuff
  }

  public bool CanShowPDF(object param)
  {
        if (SelItm.Any())
        {
            return true;
        }
            
        return false;
  }

}
```

But when I run the app I get the below error on line `if (SelItm.Any())`

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

What am I doing incorrectly ?

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding SelItm, ElementName=myGrid}"` What is Selltm?...  That property doesn't exist on a datagrid.

Comment: That still doesn't fix the problem.  You are pointing CommandParameter to the element myGrid. That means the path isn't pointing to the viewmodel but the datagrid with a path of myGrid.SelItm which doesn't exist. Change SelItm -> SelectedItems.

Comment: You use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.SelItm)` to check if a string variable has a value. In your case, `SelItm` is obviously `NULL`. It is `NULL` because `DataGrid.SelectedItem` is of type `object` and cannot be casted to `string` (wrong item type). The type is the data item of the collection that is bound to `DataGrid.SelectedItem`

Comment: In addition the Button.CommandParameter binding is wrong. Right now, it doesn't have any effect as you don't reference the parameter object in your code. But in case you want to reference it from your command handlers, you would fail.

Comment: @BionicCode using `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Seltm))` did the job, btw regarding Button.CommandParameter binding I initially didn't add that to my code but since I was getting the error mentioned in my question I tried adding that part, that didn't work either. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three options.

**Option 1 - Codebehind**

Add an event handler to the `SelectionChanged` event on the `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelItm ,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged"
          Name="myGrid"...
```

The `SelectionChanged` event will be invoked when there's a full row selected. (You can set the `SelectionUnit` as "`Rows`" on the `DataGrid` explicitly) Otherwise use the `SelectedCellsChanged` event.

In the handler of the `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void DataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args) 
{
    myButton.IsEnabled = myGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
}
```

**Option 2**
You can bind the `SelectedItem` property on the `DataGrid`, to your viewmodel.

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelItm ,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInDataGrid}"
          Name="myGrid"...
```

In the viewmodel, simplified and also assuming your vm implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
private object _selectedItemInDg;

public object SelectedItemInDataGrid 
{
    set { 
        _selectedItemInDg = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItemInDataGrid ));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnabled)); 
        PreviewButtonClicked?.UpdateCanExecute();
    }
    get => _selectedItemInDg;
}

public bool IsButtonEnabled => _selectedItemInDg != null;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string name) 
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

And your button:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}" Command="..." CommandParameter="...">Content of button</Button>
```

**Option 3 - In CanExecute**

You've got a method in your viewmodel, `CanShowPDF(object param)`, which determines for the `RelayCommand` wether the command can be executed or not. WPF enables/disables the button automatically based on the `CanExecute` method of an `ICommand` instance.
I'd add a method to the `RelayCommand` class:

```
public void UpdateCanExecute() {
    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke();
}
```

Call the `UpdateCanExecute` method on your `RelayCommand` instance every time something changes that would affect the result of `CanShowPDF`.

**The exception**

You ask about an exception you get:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

Probably you are calling a method on something that is null at that moment.
But it's hard to figure out the cause with the given information in the question and I don't actually know what `SelItm` is, although seen the name we could guess.

Comment: Can you show how to do your *Option 2* viewmodel part for older c# versions like C# 5.0? Also as per your *Option 3* I'm not sure where and how do I Call the `UpdateCanExecute` method on my `RelayCommand` instance ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also, the viewmodel part is not dependent on the C# version as far as I know. It should be valid for all versions. What don't you understand so far?

Comment: In the viewmodel part declaring properties using `=>` doesn't seem to work on older c# version as far as I know. Also, I already have a `OnPropertyChanged` method in a base viewmodel class (https://codeshare.io/r9VNXz). Furthermore, what would be the `CommandParameter` in your option 2 solution?

Comment: Change the line with the `=>` to `get { return _selectedItemInDg; }`. The `OnPropertyChanged` parts in my code example is redundant, just to remember you should notify a property update. And your command parameter can be anything you want.

Comment: How do I convert `public bool IsButtonEnabled => _selectedItemInDg != null;` to older c# code ?

Comment: `public bool IsButtonEnabled { get { return _selectedItemInDg != null;}} `